# How can I read block data from chainbase memory of a running node?

Tags: accounts, account-name, chainbase

I am running nodeos on my local machine. I can get the account data for an account by hitting the chain/get_account API. However, I wish to extend its functionality in the form of a plugin without hitting the API but by writing the code to access it internally.
Can someone suggest a method to access the data present in shared memory of the node?

Answer (score 0):

You could see the source code in EOS:

There is a function called `get_account` in [plugins/chain_plugin/chain_plugin.cpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/ced8d7db063371aabe8deadb4120767a1d2406a0/plugins/chain_plugin/chain_plugin.cpp#L1680)